# Download Images Glide in Adapter before Showing List

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a customzied ListAdapter that contains one image and 2 text Fields.

```
public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, String[] imgid) {
        super(context, R.layout.listcateg, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context = context;
    this.itemname = itemname;
    this.imgid = imgid;

   }

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listcateg, null, true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
   final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description " + itemname[position]);


    Glide.with(getContext())
            .load("http://..."+imgid[position])
            .asBitmap()
            .override(100, 100)
            .into(imageView);
    return rowView;

};

}
```

This adapter is called from an activity that contains this code :

```
CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
 list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.catlist);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My issue is that , every time i open the activity for the 1st time, the activity is loaded, quickly and i have to wait around 10s for the images to show.
How can i force the activity not to load until glide has finished downloading the iimages.
This issue happens only the 1st time. Later on, when i close and reopen the application, the pictures are shown almost immediately (as i guess they reside in cache).

Regards.

Comment: Try to add .dontAnimate() before .into(imageView) , for loading image using glide, it might reduce the time for loading images

Answer (score 0):

May be you could hide / show or load the activity using listener.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054420/set-visibility-of-progress-bar-gone-on-completion-of-image-loading-using-glide-l/31675796#31675796) is a link that could help.