# What's the fix for 'One type argument expected for Interface RequestListener<R : Any!> in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Actually I am new to Kotlin, have been working on a project, badly stuck at this, before posting up this question have looked at several other articles and posts, but non of them turned to be helpful.

[Here's the actual shot from the Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbcuj.png)

What's wrong with this piece of code? 
Also, it says...
`onException overrides nothing.`
`onResourceReady overrides nothing.`

```
 Glide.with(this@SetupUserActivity).load(storedPhotoUrl)
                               .listener(object : RequestListener<String, Drawable> {
                                override fun onException(e: Exception?, model: String?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                                    progress_bar_setup_user_img.visibility = View.GONE
                                    return false; }

                                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: String?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFromMemoryCache: Boolean, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                                    progress_bar_setup_user_img.visibility = View.GONE
                                    return false
                                }

                            }).into(user_img_setup)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your request listener to this : `object : RequestListener<Drawable>`

```
Glide.with(this@SetupUserActivity).load(storedPhotoUrl)
                               .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
.........
```

I think the reason you're having that problem is because you're overriding the wrong `RequestListener` potentially.

Try looking at this post for any extra help : [Glide callback after success in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273955/glide-callback-after-success-in-kotlin)

you have to override these methods :

```
override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                            }

                            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                            }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I have replace `GlideDrawable` with `Drawable` coz GlideDrawable is obsolete now, and gives an unresolved error, However just using `Drawable` works fine...

Comment: Wooh. It bought a slight difference, now the error just lies in `object` and the two `override` part. It says `Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member` and the same previous error for the `override`

Comment: Woohoo! You really helped me get through this buddy. It worked. Just a bit of tweak and `override` was done as you mentioned. Also `dataSource: com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource?` (you can update that). 
Thanks a lot. :)


(Yes, it's Alt+Enter for Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Glide.with(this@SetupUserActivity).load(storedPhotoUrl)
        .listener(object : RequestListener< Drawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(
                e: GlideException?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable>?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Drawable?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

        }).into(user_img_setup)
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks... Even this works with a bit of tweaks (as mentioned in the 1st answer for this thread). :)