# Failed to load gif images with glide

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set gif wallpaper but the app crashes.
This works fine with simple images(png, jpg)

Error message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

```
Glide.with(this).load(getIntent().getStringExtra("images")).into(imageView);

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        WallpaperManager manager =  WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), "Set Wallpaper Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Toasty.warning(this, "Wallpaper not load yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }
```

I want to set gif wallpaper(Live wallpaper)

Comment: Tried removing the cast `(BitmapDrawable)`? Because a GifDrawable can't be casted to a BitmapDrawable

Answer (score 2):

`GifDrawable` is a child of `Drawable` which is returned by `getDrawable()`, previously loaded using,

```
Glide.with(this).load(getIntent().getStringExtra("images")).into(imageView);
```

so `GifDrawable` and `BitmapDrawable` are siblings so cannot be casted to each other.

Alternatively, you can use `getFirstFrame()` to get the `Bitmap` as

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ((GifDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getFirstFrame();
```

Comment: @MarsadMaqsood missed the casting change, use `((GifDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getFirstFrame()`

Comment: ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: @MarsadMaqsood first, bitmaps are not gif so you need to write own wallpaper service to draw gis for wallpaper. seems like the image is not loaded yet so use [RequestListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054420/set-visibility-of-progress-bar-gone-on-completion-of-image-loading-using-glide-l) and move the bit code inside `onResourceReady`

Comment: @MarsadMaqsood yes, handle the logic of drawing of each frame inside draw but glide gives you access to only first frame, not all frames so might want to use any another lib maybe Fresco can help or you can write your own `ResourceDecoder` for glide to process and access frames